Try to add an activity to a react-native project but failed
When adding an activity to the project, gradle will add latest androidx dependencies automatically, which is not supported by current react-native version. So I tried to implement old androidx manually.
(complile sdk version = 33)
I add these in build.gradle(:app), but it doesn't work
implementation('androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0')  
implementation('androidx.transition:transition:1.4.1')
implementation('androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0')

It still uses latest androidx, which causes build failure.

1. Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs.

         :app is currently compiled against android-33.
       
         Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
         plugin 7.4.2 is 33.
       
         Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
         plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
         compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
       
         Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
         allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
         targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
         minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
         on).

2. Dependency 'androidx.transition:transition:1.5.0' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the Android APIs.


..etc

I am trying to add an activity to my application, but build failed when I try to run the app
because compile sdk version is lower than requirement (Auto added androidx dependencies)

Try to update gradle to change compile sdk version to 34

Description above

I tried to remove auto added dependecies by disabling useAndroidx in gradle.properties
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=false
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=false

And build failed when I try to run the app.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Configuration `:app:debugRuntimeClasspath` contains AndroidX dependencies, but the  `android.useAndroidX` property is not enabled, which may cause runtime issues.
Set `android.useAndroidX=true` in the `gradle.properties` file and retry.  




